# Issues calling external javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, file, external

I have a simple HTML file containing a list and a JS function that modifies the text of a list item when clicked on.

The code works when i have the HTML and the JS script inside the same .html file, but I would like to separate the JS code and put it in an external .js file and I can't seem to get the JS function to work when it's in the file.
I have provided the HTML and the JS code below.

Thank you in advance!!

My html code containing the referenced js script is as follows(js file is in the same directory):

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li id="homePage">Home
        </li>
        <li id="bookPage">Books
        </li>
        <li id="videoPage">Videos
        </li>
    </ul>

    <script src="navbar_listener.js"></script>
</nav>
```

The code found in navbar_listener.js is as follows:

```
function modifyText()
{
var t2 = document.getElementById("videoPage");
if (t2.innerHTML == "Videos")
{
t2.innerHTML = "VideoCHANGE";
}
else { t2.innerHTML = "Videos"; }

// add event listener to t2
var el = document.getElementById("videoPage");
el.addEventListener("click", modifyText,false);
```

Comment: It should work -- provided that your `.js` file is in the same folder as `.html`. What kind of server do you use?

Comment: It worked for me. Please check if any error is logged in  your console. The code provided is working fine. i have created a fiddle for it. http://jsfiddle.net/LuKPg/

Comment: Artur is right!! Apart from that your closing curly bracket for modifyText is missing. There should be a closing bracket after the last else statement in your .js

Comment: add type="text/javascript" for <script>

Comment: I encorporated all this in my website and I found out that it works. if i put my JS import after the php block that calls on the navbar.html the JS function works. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
el.addEventListener("click", modifyText,false);
```

to

```
el.onclick= modifyText;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error. You missed a closing curly bracket at the end of your method. Try indenting your code better and also check the browser console for errors. It is a good way for debugging.

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li id="homePage">Home</li>
    <li id="bookPage">Books</li>
    <li id="videoPage">Videos</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<script src="navbar_listener.js"></script>
```

And the JS file:

```
function modifyText(){
  var t2 = document.getElementById("videoPage");
  if (t2.innerHTML == "Videos"){
    t2.innerHTML = "VideoCHANGE";
  } else {
    t2.innerHTML = "Videos";
  }
} // YOU MISSED THIS ONE.

// add event listener to t2
var el = document.getElementById("videoPage");
el.addEventListener("click", modifyText,false);
```